# Angular passing variable between two directives with EventEmitter

Tags: angular, emit

I want to pass variable between two directives in Angular 7

the edit code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ct49bn

The problem is when I select a customer in the list, the emitter cannot communicate with the other directive (customer_info.directive.ts)

the error is : Cannot read property 'myValueChange' of undefined
The function "myValueChange" is well defined in customer_info.directive.ts

in app.module.ts the directives are declared (import + NgModule)

Comment: update with stackblitz code editor link.

Comment: Yes, your link only is to the running app itself, not to the code.

Comment: The [mcve] should be *in the question*.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgyubq?file=src/app/app.component.html

In component -

```
@ViewChild('custInfo', { static: false }) CustomerInfo: CustomerInfoDirective;
```

In template -

```
<p>
  Choose a customer :
  <selectcustomer 
    (EventCustomerListdirective)="CustomerInfo.myValueChange($event)"> 
  </selectcustomer>
  <CustomerInfo #custInfo></CustomerInfo>
</p>
```

I think Angular way would be to get the instance of the directive with @ViewChild decorator in the component and use it in the template instead of adding it through dependency injection.

Comment: I think in this case both solutions will work perfectly, but It will be undefined in the constructor or onInit method so keep this in mind. and maybe add it to you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem is it's not telling you the myValueChange is undefined, it's telling you 'myValueChange' of undefined which means the CustomerInfo object is undefined. you have only bad naming here... the `CustomerInfo.myValueChange($event)` shoud be `CustomerInfoDirective.myValueChange($event)`

because you gave it that name in constructor:

```
constructor(
  private CustomerListDirective: CustomerListDirective,
  private CustomerInfoDirective: CustomerInfoDirective 
){}
```

then it should work as you wish :)

Comment: thanks for your response, i changed to "CustomerInfoDirective" but same result

Comment: @freaks but the error is gone, was that error the only problem?

Comment: i still have Error: Cannot read property 'myValueChange' of undefined
after the change to CustomerInfoDirective.myValueChange($event)

Comment: It worked for me. funny. but i see you have better solution already :)